# Recycler inside bottom tablyout not showing last row

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, bottom-sheet

I have a coordinate layout inside which there is custom `ViewPager` and bottom *TabLayout*. **Now issue is `RecyclerView` of one of fragment of `ViewPager` not scrolling properly. Its hiding the last row.**

**tablayout.xml**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<CustomViewPager    
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/AppTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorBottomBar"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**CustomViewPager**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
            private boolean enabled;

            public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                this.enabled = true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                if (enabled)
                    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                else
                    return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                return enabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
            }

            public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
                this.enabled = enabled;
            }

            public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
                return enabled;
            }

        }
```

**ViewPager Fragmet having recyclerview**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/reload"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_refresh"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/sort_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:weightSum="1">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorBottomBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sort_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**In above picture , you see that last row of `RecyclerView` is not completely visible.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put custom pager and tab layout in relative layout and set custom pager above tab layout like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CustomViewPager    
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/@+id/tab_layout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/AppTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorBottomBar"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hey it worked. Thanks alot for saving time. And also if you could upvote question i will be grateful. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 1):

In your ‍`tablayout.xml` use this code instead of yours:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <CustomViewPager    
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                style="@style/AppTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorBottomBar"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry , it wont work. Now my view pager fargment not showing.